# readdir hangs up if libpocofoundation is linked with my tiny app

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I've started debbuging on some app, which hangs up in a loop based on `readdir` call.
Step by step I've cut everything but problem code, this is it:

So, in basic, it shows name of first entry and nothing more. It even does not exits, just waiting for something.

Also, I've found, that if don't lin it against `libpocofoundation`, it works.
But I have to do it because it used in the original app. 
I'm a little bit confused, I don't use `Poco` in this example in any way, but it some way hangs it.
Please help me, I'm in panic :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char TMP_DIR[] = "/opt";
    DIR *dir = opendir(TMP_DIR);
    std::cerr
     << readdir(dir)->d_name
      << readdir(dir)->d_name
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So... I don't know why it was happening. So I just dropped libpoco.